# nameerror:name 'array' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I copy-pasted this program in pyscripter 2.7. I downloaded numpy and scipy for python 2.7 too.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
array([[1, 2],
      [3, 4]])
linalg.inv(A)
array([[-2. ,  1. ],
      [ 1.5, -0.5]])
A.dot(linalg.inv(A)) #double check
array([[  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
      [  4.44089210e-16,   1.00000000e+00]])
```

but it doesn't be run and is see this: `Name Error: name 'array' is not defined`.
what should I do?

Comment: Did you copy paste this? This seems to have the output attached to it.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have attached the output in the script you are trying to run, hence the error.
Executing the following gives a similar error -

```
>>> array([1, 2])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    array([1, 2])
NameError: name 'array' is not defined
```

And this matches your script.

```
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> A
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Your original script is.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
linalg.inv(A)
A.dot(linalg.inv(A)) #double check
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *import* the `array` type, or refer to it directly:

```
from numpy import array
```

or use `np.array` to refer to it.

However, you seem to be looking at the *output* of the script as well as the code itself:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
linalg.inv(A)
A.dot(linalg.inv(A)) #double check
```

Running that code in my interactive Python interpreter prompt, I see:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import linalg
>>> A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> linalg.inv(A)
array([[-2. ,  1. ],
       [ 1.5, -0.5]])
>>> A.dot(linalg.inv(A)) #double check
array([[  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  8.88178420e-16,   1.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: oh!thanks i had one question.why 'scipy' and 'numpy' dont be bold and dont change their colors to blue in my pyscripter?like this :http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/linalg.html

Comment: I have no idea; I don't use pyscripter myself.

Comment: no, Kalra is right, the array lines are prettified output...